# How can I implement formula in Excel with specific interval

Tags: excel-formula

I am Shozib. I am here to get the answer for my question. My question is How can I implement formula in Excel with specific interval. Actually I mean I want to implement a formula on

Row 1 then

Row 4 then

Row 8 then and so on.

Basically with the interval of 3 I want to apply formula but don not know how to do it. If anyone can help me in this problem then please help me.

Thanks

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @shozib - If the interval is 3 then why 1, 4, **8**?

Comment: Actually the task is  currently I have data in coloumn.

Comment: Actually the task is  currently I have data in one column. Now I want to transfer it to three columns, which is transposing I guess.  The problem is I have the formula but don't know how to implement.    As an example The record in A1,A2,A3 should be transfer to B1,C1,D1 and after that the data in A4,A5,A6 should be transfer to B4,C4,D4

Answer (score 1):

With hardly any detail included in your question, this may not be what you intended, but this is my interpretation...

If you have a formula, say `=(4+4)` that you want to appear on every 3rd row starting with `Row 1`. (ie., `1,4,7,10...` -- *not* like your example since it doesn't make sense) then you could put this formula in a cell on `Row 1`:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-1,3)=0,(4+4),"")
```

...and then copy or 'fill' the formula down as far as needed.

- `ROW()` returns the current Row Number
- check if `ROW()-1` is divisible by 3 with Modulus (`MOD`), which returns the *remainder* after dividing by 3.  If the result is zero, then `ROW()-1` is evenly divisible by 3.
- `IF` the result of the expression is `TRUE` then show the formula.
- `IF` the result of the expression is `FALSE` then show an empty string (`""`)

  [image]

Comment: This is working. Just one more question, actually the sequence on which I want to implement the formula is 1,5,9,13,17....

Comment: @Shozib your question gives 1, 4, 8 and now you say 1, 5, 9, 13 - if you are not sure of what you are working with, how can we be expected to get it right. The answer you have been given is easily editable to give you the spacing you want.

Comment: I got got it right from your answer,  Now the formula which I am using is =IF(MOD(ROW()-1,4)=0,( TRANSPOSE(A4149:A4151) ),"") , just one thing more, If you please help, 
The rows which are to be copied in to columns are mostly hyperlinks, but when I applied this formula, it worked perfectly (converted rows to columns with desired interval) but did not copied the hyperlinks as well. 
How can I tackle this?